# Is it possible to center a control(GenericTile) in the middle of the screen in View.xml without using css?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

im new to ui5 so i apologize if my question is too easy. i have a Generatic Tile that supposed to display events from Odata v4. the problem i have is that this tile is required to be in the middle of the screen(knowing that there is nothing else around). i tried using FlexBox(and many other classes) and i was only able to center it, but not to get it in the middle of the screen. is it possible to do it using only my View.xml?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SMGI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to wrap your Tile with a VerticalLayout or VBox (which extends FlexBox) and set height='100%' justifyContent ='Center'
Something like:

[How to vertically center align my form container in openui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032765/how-to-vertically-center-align-my-form-container-in-openui5)

or this:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.FlexBox/sample/sap.m.sample.FlexBoxBasicAlignment

Kind regards
Sebastian